# Can't turn off logging for specific appender

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j

Here log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="Console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- l, L, M - is extremely slow. It's use should be avoided unless execution 
                speed is not an issue. -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{[dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} %l %p:%n    %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="File" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Encoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <param name="File" value="logs/trace.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- l, L, M - is extremely slow. It's use should be avoided unless execution 
                speed is not an issue. -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{[dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} %l %p:%n    %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="File" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Use **org.apache.log4j**

```
import org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserOptions.class);;

AppenderSkeleton consoleAppender = (AppenderSkeleton) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("Console");
        AppenderSkeleton fileAppender = (AppenderSkeleton) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender("File");
        if (!getOptionsAdditionalLoggingIsToConsole()) {
            consoleAppender.setThreshold(Level.OFF);
        }
        if (!getOptionsAdditionalLoggingIsToFile()) {
            fileAppender.setThreshold(Level.OFF);
}
```

So as result I can turn off logging for specific appender (**Console, File**)

Nice.

Here my **log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration package="log4j.test" status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="baseDir">logs</Property>
        <Property name="patterLayout">%d{[dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS]} [%t] %l %p:%n
            %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${patterLayout}" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${baseDir}/application.log"
            filePattern="${baseDir}/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"
            ignoreExceptions="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${patterLayout}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <!-- Levels from lowest to highest are: ALL, TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, 
            ERROR, FATAL, OFF. The root category is used for all loggers unless a more 
            specific logger matches. If none of the loggers are assigned a level, then 
            all loggers inherit the level of the root logger which is set to DEBUG by 
            default -->
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File" />
        </Root>
    
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now I want to use **org.slf4j**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Appender;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig;

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserOptions.class);;

LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
        Configuration configuration = loggerContext.getConfiguration();

        LoggerConfig rootLoggerConfig = configuration.getLoggerConfig("");
        Appender consoleAppender = rootLoggerConfig.getAppenders().get("Console");
        Appender fileAppender = rootLoggerConfig.getAppenders().get("File");

        if (!getOptionsAdditionalLoggingIsToConsole()) {
            consoleAppender.setThreshold(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
}
```

But I get error:

```
error: cannot find symbol method setThreshold(Level)
```

Answer (score 1):

*"Now I want to use **org.slf4j**"*: if you just want to use SLF4j, you can use its Log4j 1.2 binding. I assume you also want to upgrade the logging backend from Log4j 1.2 to Log4j 2.x.

You obtain a compilation error, since [`LoggerConfig`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/LoggerConfig.html) does not have a `setThreshold` method. Therefore you must use the other methods at your disposal.

If you just want to remove the console appender use:

```java
        LoggerConfig rootLoggerConfig = configuration.getRootLogger();
        rootLoggerConfig.removeAppender("Console");
```

If you want to keep it, but silence it, you need to remove it and add it with a different level:

```java
        LoggerConfig rootLoggerConfig = configuration.getRootLogger();
        Appender consoleAppender = rootLoggerConfig.getAppenders().get("Console");
        rootLoggerConfig.removeAppender("Console");
        rootLoggerConfig.addAppender(consoleAppender, Level.OFF, null);
```

**Edit**: You need also to replace the line:

```java
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
```

with

```java
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
```

since (as stated in the Javadoc for `LogManager.getContext()`):

> WARNING - The LoggerContext returned by this method may not be the LoggerContext used to create a Logger for the calling class.

Comment: Method "rootLoggerConfig.removeAppender("Console");" not help. Logs generate on console after start application.

Comment: Try `LogManager.getContext(false)` instead of `LogManager.getContext()`, since the two may give different contexts.